# SQL query to calculate a percentage of a particular String in a column out of all rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a very simple table that contains Status_var and description. You can see example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e0d1/5

I need to be able to count how many 'Pass' string occurences are in Status_var column and calculate percentage. Example table below:
[image]

In the above example, we have 2 "Pass" and 1 "Fail" occurences. The result should be 66%.

I have found a very simmillar solution to this problem in this post:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311416/mysql-getting-the-percentage-of-an-occurrence

And I tried to implement it in sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e0d1/22

But it does not work
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For your mentioned link i would go with:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Status_var='Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(*) 
FROM ForgeRock;
```

To get the result 66.

Answer (score 2):

This could be more efficient, since will count only the ones with `Status_var = 'Pass'` :

```
select 'Pass' as Status_var, count(case when Status_var = 'Pass' then 1 end )*100/ count(*) AS PERCENT
from ForgeRock
```

Also an index On `Status_var` will be helpfull

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT 'Pass', [...]`? You wouldn't need the surrounding query then ;)

Comment: `sum(count(*))`??? If there's only one summand anyway, why yet the aggregate function?

Comment: Thanks @Aconcagua I have just drunk my coffee :)

Comment: `over()` is not needed either

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple approach is adding another `SELECT` around your query specifying the appropriate condition (you'll have to give the calculated column a name for); this might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( --                                              vvvvvvvvvvvvv (!)

  select Status_var, count(Status_var)*100/sum(count(*)) over() AS percentage
  from ForgeRock
  group by Status_var

) sp WHERE status_var = 'Pass'
```

**EDIT:** Your second query you adopted from the other answer actually seems to be fine – on **mySQL**! See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e95b9f/13) – but you need to set mySQL as database, you tried on MS SQL which doesn't seem to accept comparisons at this place; it seems to interpret the equal-sign as assignment, as the query

```
SELECT status_var, Status_var = 'Pass' FROM ForgeRock
```

reveals...

Comment: Yeah that seems to work fine! Although I am not sure how efficient is that. Since I will be using this query in AWS database it is important to query as little information as possible to reduce the costs. 
Im just curious, maybe you know why the method used in this sql fiddle wont work?
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e0d1/22

Comment: @TheBestPlayer Agree, it indeed is not efficient. The other answers are superior. An inefficient, but working solution is better than none at all, though – at the time of writing no others existed ;) On the other hand it's a general *quick and dirty* pattern to filter results from a query that might be fine for testing purposes, as long as it won't enter production code.

Comment: @TheBestPlayer Now wondering how none of all of us discovered the most naive approach: `SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM ForgeRock WHERE status_var = 'Pass') * 100 / (SELECT count(*) FROM ForgeRock)` – not sure how efficient this is, maybe the a clever DMBS might notice only having to iterate once, though letting postgreSQL *explain* showed that at least this one doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this it will return you percentage for both status pass/fail

```
select Status_var,count(Status_var)*100/sum(count(*)) over()
from ForgeRock
group by Status_var
```

Result :

> Fail : 33 Pass : 66

If need response only for pass then try this -

```
select Status_var,perc from (
select Status_var,count(Status_var)*100/sum(count(*)) over() as perc
from ForgeRock
group by Status_var)t where Status_var='Pass'
```

> Result : Pass : 66

Comment: Really like the general solution (for all entries), second one suffers from the same disadvantages than mine, so if it was only for a single value I'd go one of the other two, (none of ours)... Remains nice if filtering *multiple* values (`WHERE ... IN (...)`) ;)

Comment: yeah agreed, i would also go for generic one for all the entries.